# Powershell -- Get-ChildItem Directory full path and lastaccesstime

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I am attempting to output full directory path and lastaccesstime in one line.

Needed --
R:\Directory1\Directory2\Directory3, March 10, 1015

What I am getting -- 
R:\Directory1\Directory2\Directory3

March 10, 1015

Here is my code, It isn't that complicated, but it is beyond me.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "R:\" -Directory | foreach-object -process{$_.FullName, $_.LastAccessTime} | Where{ $_.LastAccessTime -lt [datetime]::Today.AddYears(-2) } | Out-File c:\temp\test.csv
```

I have used foreach-object in the past in order to ensure I do not truncate the excessively long directory names and paths, but never used it when pulling two properties. I would like the information to be on all one line, but haven't been successful. Thanks in advance for the assist.

Comment: When I unerstand you right, the only thing you're missing is the comma between the two properties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend filtering (`Where-Object`) before selecting the properties you want. Also I think you want to replace `ForEach-Object` with `Select-Object`, and lastly I think you want `Export-Csv` rather than `Out-File`. Example:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "R:\" -Directory |
  Where-Object { $_.LastAccessTime -lt [DateTime]::Today.AddYears(-2) } |
  Select-Object FullName,LastAccessTime |
  Export-Csv C:\temp\test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Absolutely! A primary concept in PowerShell is "Filter left, format right" - in other words, do your filtering as early as possible, and your data structuring and output at the last possible minute. This minimizes the overall processing you do, because you're not processing entities that you'll eventually discard as not meeting your criteria.  Bryce gets an upvote because of the clear and detailed explanation of his process; you get the upvote because your final code is the better solution - and your answer should be the one finally Accepted.

Comment: Thanks Bill. This is perfect. Also thanks to Jeff for the explanation. Greatly appreciate everyone here.

Answer (score 1):

We can get your output on one line pretty easily, but to make it easy to read we may have to split your script out to multiple lines.  I'd recommend saving the script below as a ".ps1" which would allow you to right click and select "run with powershell" to make it easier in the future.  This script could be modified to play around with more inputs and variables in order to make it more modular and work in more situations, but for now we'll work with the constants you provided.

```
$dirs = Get-ChildItem -Path "R:\" -Directory
```

We'll keep the first line you made, since that is solid and there's nothing to change.

```
$arr = $dirs | Select-Object {$_.FullName, $_.LastAccessTime} |  Where-Object{ $_.LastAccessTime -lt [datetime]::Today.AddYears(-2) }
```

For the second line, we'll use "Select-Object" instead.  In my opinion, it's a lot easier to create an array this way.  We'll want to deal with the answers as an array since it'll be easiest to post the key,value pairs next to each other this way.  I've expanded your "Where" to "Where-Object" since it's best practice to use the full cmdlet name instead of the alias.

Lastly, we'll want to convert our "$arr" object to csv before putting in the temp out-file.

```
ConvertTo-CSV $arr | Out-File "C:\Temp\test.csv"
```

Putting it all together, your final script will look like this:

```
$dirs = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\git" -Directory
$arr = $dirs | Select-Object {$_.FullName, $_.LastAccessTime} | Where{ $_.LastAccessTime -lt [datetime]::Today.AddYears(-2) }
ConvertTo-CSV $arr | Out-File "C:\Temp\test.csv"
```

Again, you can take this further by creating a function, binding it to a cmdlet, and creating parameters for your path, output file, and all that fun stuff.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: This is a good explanation of your revision to the querent's code, but see Bill's answer and my comment.